# Separate in two words

Tags: c#, .net, string

Consider the following example,

*Example:* 1:1 Hello.

Now i would like to have `("1:1")` and `("Hello")` in two separate string variables.Any solution is greatly appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get exactly 2 strings out of a string that contains at least one but potentially having more spaces, you  can use this [`String.Split(Char[], Int32)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/c1bs0eda.aspx) overload in which you can specify the maximum number of splits (substrings) needed.

Example usages:

`"1:1 Hello".Split(new char[] {' '}, 2)` this will give you two strings `1:1` and `Hello`

`"1:1 Hello world".Split(new char[] {' '}, 2)` will give you two strings `1:1` and `Hello world`

Comment: This will give at MOST 2 strings, not EXACTLY 2 strings. If the input was `"1:1"` the output will only be `1:1` with no second string.

Comment: @DocMax true, but that's the case with all Split overloads, we assume the requirement is at least two words, answering the specific question here

Comment: I just want to be cautious because the OP doesn't specify what kinds of input he will be using and because your use of the phrase "no matter what" may mislead someone who is unfamiliar with this overload.

Comment: @DocMax edited. The main point which I wanted to emphasize (but failed I guess since I didn't put it in the answer body initially) is that it looks like the OP may run into more problems if he uses the most popular Split overload if the input contains more spaces which is 50/50 chance I'd guess. The problems which may arise from this overload are the same as the popular overload but if he has more spaces he'll have less problems if he uses this overload.

Comment: I want to store 1.1 in one column and hello in another in database.

Comment: @TinKerBell could the `hello` input be more then one word ? could it be a phrase with like two or three words ?

Comment: yeah may be like this also "1:13 And the evening and the morning were the third day."

Comment: @TinKerBell in this case definitely use this method.  "1:13 And the evening and the morning were the third day.".Split(' ', 2) will give you a string[] array with 2 elements only `"1:13"` and `"And the evening and the morning were the third day."`

Comment: @user1416420 Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid argument --Giving error like this -TinKerBell

Comment: Ops sorry I gave it wrongly, edited the answer. It should be like this:  `"1:13 And the evening and the morning were the third day.".Split(new char[] {' '}, 2)`

Comment: @TinKerBell no problem:) u r welcome

Answer (score 3):

Use [`String.Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.string.split%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) with the space character.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) to separate base on the empty space.

```
var str = "1:1 Hello";
var s = str.Split(' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

I have appended space to str1 to avoid exceptions if string (str) doesn't contain space. If there are no chances of having strings without spaces, remove the additional space in str1.

```
var str = "1:1 Hello";
var str1 = (str+" ").Split(' ');
var firststr = str1[0];
var hellostr = str1[1];
```

Comment: this will split in to three item

Comment: yes, right. But I am taking only first two items, third item is safe side for exception cases. OP asked in two different variables, so it works for variables not having spaces too.

Comment: There is no exception if the string doesn't contain a white space. The result will contain only str[0] with the whole string. There is no need to add an extra empty space.

Comment: @alexandrudicu, There will be array index out of bounds exception if string doesnt contain space and try to access str[1]

Comment: if my sentence is 1.1 hello kitty then 1.1 in one variable and hello kitty in another variable to be store. Am first time working in C# plz help me :(

Answer (score 0):

If Split() is not enough, you may consider regular expression.

Comment: Care to give an example of how you would split the text with a regular expression?